# How can I get ant argument in commandline in build xml?

Tags: ant

How can I get ant input argument in commandline in build xml???

I have command:

```
C:\> Ant TestApp WebAppUSA   WebSvcEurope  -Denv dev
```

In build.xml, I hope to get these three arguments values:
TestApp 
WebAppUSA
WebSvcEurope
separately,

How to get these arguments values in build xml???

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `-Dproperty=value` option, where property is the name of the property, and value is the value for that property.